# Using dart RPC and shelf_auth for some procedures

Tags: authentication, dart, dart-shelf

I'm using [`dart-lang/rpc`](https://github.com/dart-lang/rpc) with the [`shelf_rpc`](https://github.com/dart-lang/shelf_rpc) package.

Some of my Resources require authentication. I decided to go with [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) and want to use the `JwtSessionHandler` from [`shelf_auth`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf_auth).

My simplified setup looks like this:

```
final ApiServer _apiServer = new ApiServer();

main() async {
  var loginMiddleware = authenticate([new UsernamePasswordAuthenticator(lookupByUsernamePassword)],
      sessionHandler: new JwtSessionHandler('my app', 'shhh secret', usernameLookup), allowHttp: true);

  _apiServer.addApi(new Api());

  // Create a Shelf handler for your RPC API.
  var apiHandler = shelf_rpc.createRpcHandler(_apiServer);

  var apiRouter = shelf_route.router()
    ..add('/api', null, apiHandler, exactMatch: false);

  var handler = const shelf.Pipeline()
      .addMiddleware(loginMiddleware)
      .addMiddleware(shelf.logRequests())
      .addHandler(apiRouter.handler);


  var server = await shelf_io.serve(handler, '0.0.0.0', 8087);
}

/// Stub implementation
lookupByUsernamePassword(String username, String password) async =>
  new Some(new Principal(username));
/// Stub implementation
usernameLookup(String username) async =>
  new Some(new Principal(username));
```

How can I only add the `loginMiddleware` to requests that start with `/account` (for example)? Or even better: is it possible to define the `loginMiddleware` on the RPC Resource itself (instead of defining a path prefix which can potentially change and annul the authentication)?

Comment: Good question. I've never used the rpc package myself, but as it is not a native shelf package (only adapted via shelf_rpc) I don't see how you could  easily use any shelf middleware (such as authentication) anywhere within your rpc resources.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, although it doesn't seem to be the cleanest.

Instead of adding the `loginMiddleware` to the pipeline, I add it to the route like this:

```
var apiRouter = shelf_route.router()
  ..add('$_API_PREFIX/v1/account', null, apiHandler, exactMatch: false, middleware: loginMiddleware)
  ..add('$_API_PREFIX', null, apiHandler, exactMatch: false);
```

This registers the apiHandler twice, but the first route only matches `/account` routes, and adds the `loginMiddleware`.

Answer (score 1):

You would just create a handler that only does something when that path starts with account.  This should work.

```
 shelf.Handler _accountHandler(shelf.Handler innerHandler) {
   return (shelf.Request request) {
   if (request.url.path.startsWith("/account")) {
   /// do something here
   }
   return innerHandler(request);
 };
```